# What's the purpose of having both db level and code level uniqueness validations in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, unique-index

I see a table that has both db-level and code-level validations in Rails.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX some_index_name ON joined_table_name USING btree (user_id, restriction_id);
```

and code level:

```
class SomeJoinTable
validates_uniqueness_of :restriction_id, :scope => :user_id
end
```

What's the benefit of having both?

Comment: This is explained clearly in [*Concurrency and integrity*](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_uniqueness_of)

Comment: I think it explains why you need database level validations, but my question also is asking why can't we just have database-level validations.

Comment: @Jwan622 I updated my answer to address your question.

Answer (score 10):

To quote an [excellent article by thoughtbot](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/the-perils-of-uniqueness-validations):

> When you persist a user instance, Rails will validate your model by running a SELECT query to see if any user records already exist with the provided email. Assuming the record proves to be valid, Rails will run the INSERT statement to persist the user. This works great in development and may even work in production if you’re running a single instance of a single process web server.
>
> But you’re not running a lone instance of WEBrick, are you? No, to maximize requests per minute, you’re running Unicorn on multiple Heroku dynos, each with multiple web processes. Let’s take a look at what happens if just two of these processes are trying to create a user with the same email address at around the same time:

[image: thoughtbot example image]

> ...you can create the unique index when generating the migration or model with:

`rails generate model user email:string:uniq`

> With the index in place, how does the above scenario play out now?

[image: thoughtbot example image 2]

> Now we have the database acting as our last line of defense in our war on inconsistent data. The second save operation will generate an ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique exception.
>
> **In Conclusion**
>
> Rails does many things, but data integrity validations are not one of them. Your relational database is designed to enforce data integrity; let it.

**EDIT**

Added example of why you'd use `validates_uniqueness_of` in addition to the db constraint (per OP's comment):

> I think it explains why you need database level validations, but my question also is asking why can't we just have database-level validations.

**ANSWER**

To further quote [thoughtbot's article](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/the-perils-of-uniqueness-validations):

> The second save operation will generate an ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique exception. In most cases, this will result in an application error. If you need to provide a better experience, you can rescue and handle that exception in the controller action or use rescue_from at the class level.

Let's see this in action at the class level.

With database-level constraint only:

```
class Foo < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :bar
  validates_presence_of :name
end

class Bar < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :foos
end

> Foo.create!(bar_id: 1, name: 'Poop')
> Foo.create!(bar_id: 1, name: 'Poop')
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "index_foos_on..."
```

With database constraint and application-level validation (a la `validates_uniqueness_of`):

```
class Foo < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :bar
  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_uniqueness_of :name, scope: :bar_id
end

> Foo.create!(bar_id: 1, name: 'Poop')
> Foo.create!(bar_id: 1, name: 'Poop')
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Name has already been taken
```

Answer (score 0):

> What's the benefit of having both?

Apart from the obvious "Extra security" aspect, having the `validates_uniqueness_of` adds a quality gate on your app side to check before trying to commit.

**Without validates_uniqueness_of**, it will attempt to query the database to create, so the error returns from the **database**.

**With validates_uniqueness_of**, it will query the database to see if it exists *before* trying to create, so the error returns from the **app**.  It's preferable to have errors return from the app, since you have full control.

*Also something to think about...*
I could see issues maybe later down the road, you remove that constraint from the database, but wait.. your model still has that constraint!  or vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

> What's the benefit of having both?

The db-level guard is the ultimate protection. It is what keeps your data consistent.

The app-level guard, while also doing some checks, can't be relied on to keep your data consistent. Its purpose is to **power ActiveRecord validations** (populate errors array so you can show pretty form errors, etc.)

So, if you have only the db guard, you have to do extra work to intercept db errors and show user-friendly form errors.

And if you have only app-level check, you might as well delete it. It is vulnerable to race conditions and violations **will** happen, sooner or later.